# Render Icon on custom floor tiles using OSM & Leaflet

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, maps, openstreetmap, google-indoor-maps

I need to convert the some functionality of google maps into Leaflet and OSM.
What I have is an indoor visitor tracking application that uses google maps with custom tiles (Indoor floor plan image). It plot markers on the locations of visitors (indoor) by converting X Y coordinates into Lat Lng. Its done through

```
function findLatLangFromImagePixel(imgPixel) {
    var scalingRatio = ImageWidth / 256;
    var pixel = { x: ((imgPixel.X) / scalingRatio), y: ((imgPixel.Y) / scalingRatio) };

    var point = new google.maps.Point(pixel.x + 0.5, pixel.y + 0.5);
    return map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(point);
}
```

[image]

In Leaflet maps I am trying the following code to achieve same results (using the same image/tiles):

```
var x = ImageXYLocation.X;
            var y = ImageXYLocation.Y;
            var scalingRatio = ImageWidth / 256;
            var pixel = { x: ((x) / scalingRatio), y: ((y) / scalingRatio) };
var pointXY = L.point(pixel.x + 0.5, pixel.y +0.5);

            latlng = map.layerPointToLatLng(pointXY);
latlng.lng += 180;
```

But I am getting different results. Also, I observed that as the marker switches its location on the indoor map upon changing the resolution of my screen . It seems that the marker position is dependent on my screen resolution or at zoom level.
[image]

And second zoom level
[image]

**Update:**
Map initialization code is below:

```
 if (map != null) {
            map.remove();
        }
        $("#map_canvas").html("");

        map = L.map('map_canvas', {
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 4,
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 1,
            crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        });
        var w = 6095,
            h = 3410;
        var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
        var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
        var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
        L.tileLayer('./tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 16,
            minZoom: 0,
            continuousWorld: false,
            bounds: bounds,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        map.setZoom(5);
        map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

        map.zoomControl.setPosition('bottomright');
```

**Update 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your guidance. I have been able to figure out the solution. I used the following code to get the correct LatLng

```
var x = ImageXYLocation.X;
var y = ImageXYLocation.Y;
var scalingRatio = ImageWidth / 256;
var pixel = { x: ((x / scalingRatio) * Math.pow(2, map.getZoom())), y: ((y / scalingRatio) * Math.pow(2, map.getZoom())) };

var pointXY = L.point(pixel.x + 0.5, pixel.y +0.5);

latlng = map.unproject(L.point(pixel.x, pixel.y));
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that the marker position is dependent on my screen resolution or at zoom level.

Indeed. You're using `layerPointToLatLng()`, which [according to the documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-layerpointtolatlng) (emphasis mine)...

> Given a **pixel coordinate** relative to the origin pixel, returns the corresponding geographical coordinate (for the **current zoom level**).

Leaflet has a [curious way of hiding the complexities of CRSs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310091/what-does-the-default-crs-being-epsg3857-in-leaflet-mean/310124#310124) and projections. Without seeing more of the code you're using for defining the map's CRS, or the bounds of your indoor map image, it's impossible to offer any advice other than "pay attention to what your coordinates mean".

Comment: And what's the possible range of values for `ImageXYLocation.X` and `ImageXYLocation.Y`? Are their units pixels or meters or feet or what? Where do those come from?

Comment: The range of X & Y lies within the width & height of the actual image size and these X,Y are in pixels. First, I take each of the X Y of the several scanning devices through  `e.layerPoint.x`  and  `e.layerPoint.y`. Second, there is an algorithm that uses all these devices's X Ys to find visitor's X Y on the map. So the main source is `e.layerPoint`. Do I need to use something like `L.Map.unproject(point [, zoom])` as mentioned in the [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69124/leaflet-container-coordinates-vs-layer-coordinates)

Comment: What's `e.layerPoint`? What's the relationship between that and the `ImageXYLocation` in your code from the question?

Comment: When the user place a marker on a map on that click event i take the marker X,Y through e.layerpoint. I have added the image in the question to explain my point.

Comment: In that case, just use `L.point(e.latLng)`. You don't need to touch pixel coordinates at all. See the remarks at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54816178/how-are-the-bounds-calculated-in-the-leaflet-crs-simple-tutorial/54816872#54816872 as well.