# Convert Game Coordinates to Map Coordinates and back

Tags: javascript, math, leaflet, game-development

I have a map image that is 5632 x 4096 pixels. At the moment the following code is used to get the corresponding in-game coordinates from the pixel that I have clicked on:

```
var lx = (x + 4.5) / (5632 / 5500) - 1500;
var ly = 2500.0 - (y + 5.5) / (4096 / 4000.0);
```

For example, if I click at the longitude and latitude of 2491, 4869 I am given the in-game coordinates of 2260, 937 (which is correct)

I am struggling to go the other way; to convert the in-game coordinates back to the longitude and latitude of the map. For example I want to input the in-game coordinates of 120, 844 and see where that is on the map using the longitude and latitude the function gives me.

Comment: Smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Define the `L.ImageOverlay` with the in-game coordinates instead.

Comment: Treat your transform as an equation, and solve it for x resp. y

Comment: @IvanSanchez which coordinates should I use for this (bounds) - I am not sure what the most north-western and south-western point is with the coordinates.

Comment: The in-game coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right corners of your image.

Comment: You might be able to draw inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/q/54816178/4768502

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thanks, I have measured in-game position (0,0) as the following, would this still work?
1553px from Bottom
2558px from Top
2561px from Left
3071 from Right

Comment: Again: What's the in-game coordinate corresponding to the top-left corner of your image.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Hi again, finally found out what the actual coordinates are for the top left and bottom right are:

Top left: -3000, 3000

Bottom right:  3000, -3000

Comment: OK, now add that image to the map using `L.imageOverlay(url, [[-3000,3000],[3000,-3000]])`

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thanks. However, I have done that and it still seems to be out by around 300 on the latitude axis and 70 on the longitude. The map itself also seems to be distorted (width seems to be shortened)

Comment: Are you really, absolutely, positively, definitively sure that the corners of the image map correspond to (3000,3000) in-game coordinates? Do you have a border on the image?